# How do I use the for loop in ruby to grab different values from hash tables

Tags: ruby

This is probably easy to do! I'm not able envision the loop yet, I was thinking about a nested for loop but not quite sure how to alternate between the two hashes.

Lets say I have a class with a def that containts two hash tables:

```
 class Teststuff
    def test_stuff
     letters = { "0" => " A ", "1" => " B ", "2" => " C " }
     position = {"1" => "one ", "2"=> " two ", "3"=> " three ", "4"=>" four " }

     my_array=[0,1,2,2] #this represents user input stored in an array valid to 4 elements
     array_size = my_array.size #this represents the size of the user inputed array
     element_indexer = my_array.size # parellel assignment so I can use same array for array in dex
     array_start_index = element_indexer-1 #give me the ability later to get start at index zero for my array

 #for loop?? downto upto?? 
 # trying to get loop to grab the first number "0" in element position "0", grab the hash values then
 # the loop repeats and grabs the second number "1" in element position "1" grab the hash values
 # the loop repeats and grabs the third number "2" in elements position "2" grab the hash values
 # the final iteration grabs the fourth number "2" in elements position "3" grab the hash values
 # all this gets returned when called. Out put from puts statement after grabing hash values 
 # is: **A one B two C three C four**  

     return a_string
    end
  end
```

How do I go about returning string output to the screen like this:

```
   **A one B two C three C four**
```

or simply letter position letter position...
Thanks for the help, put code up so I can try on my editor!

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you are trying to do. What does `my_array` do? It doesn't seem to be used in your code anywhere. The same for `array_size`, `element_indexer` and `array_start_index`. Where does `a_string` come from? What are `letters` and `position` used for? They aren't used anywhere, either! (In fact, *none* of your variables are used anywhere.) What is the class `Teststuff` for? It never gets instantiated. What is the method `test_stuff` for? It never gets called. Can you provide testcases for what the output should be?

Comment: At the moment, there are no parameters, so the output will *always* be the same, in which case you might just as well do `return '**A one B two C three C four**'`. Which reminds me: why is the output `**A one B two C three C four**` and not `**A one B two C three C three**` or `**A one B two C three D four**`?

Comment: Also, why is `letters` a `Hash` and not an `Array` and why do `letters` and `position` use `String` s for the keys instead of `Integer` s or the other way around, why does `my_array` use `Integer` s for the values, and not `String` s? Why are there spaces around the letters in `letters` but not in the output? Same for `position`?

Comment: edited to explain a little better. To answer comments from above:

Comment: To answer comments from above: 1. my_array is user input, array_size is a variable I set up to be able to get the .size of my_array. Element_indexer is used for parallel assignment so I can use the variable in array_start_index. Array_start_index is used to determine element position for the loop I don't know how to utilize quite yet. Never instantiated or used method as I left it open for looping examples. Simple puts statment like puts x.a_string.

Comment: To answer second comments box output A one B two C three C four was setup to jsut give a general idea based on my user array given

Comment: Third comments box I used hash as an example becasue I need to return strings as values for key/value hash , I should have just kept the keys as integers. Finally I forgot to put the spaces in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured out what it is you want, although I still have no idea what `array_size`, `element_indexer`, `array_start_index` and `TestStuff` are for.

```
def test_stuff
  letters = { "0" => " A ", "1" => " B ", "2" => " C " }
  position = {"1" => "one ", "2"=> " two ", "3"=> " three ", "4"=>" four " }

  my_array = [0, 1, 2, 2]

  "**#{my_array.map.with_index {|e, i|
    "#{letters[e.to_s].strip} #{position[(i+1).to_s].strip}"
  }.join(' ')}**"
end
```

[I took the liberty of reformatting your code to standard Ruby coding style.]

However, everything would be much simpler, if there weren't all those type conversions, and all those superfluous spaces. Also, the method would be much more useful, if it actually had a way to return different results, instead of always returning the same thing, because at the moment, it is actually exactly equivalent to

```
def test_stuff
  '**A one B two C three C four**'
end
```

Something along these lines would make much more sense:

```
def test_stuff(*args)
  letters = %w[A B C]
  position = %w[one two three four]

  "**#{args.map.with_index {|e, i| "#{letters[e]} #{position[i]}" }.join(' ')}**"
end

test_stuff(0, 1, 2, 2)
# => '**A one B two C three C four**'
```

If you don't want to pollute the `Object` namespace with your method, you could do something like this:

```
def (TestStuff = Object.new).test_stuff(*args)
  letters = %w[A B C]
  position = %w[one two three four]

  "**#{args.map.with_index {|e, i| "#{letters[e]} #{position[i]}" }.join(' ')}**"
end

TestStuff.test_stuff(0, 1, 2, 2)
# => '**A one B two C three C four**'
```

Comment: +1 for assigning a method on an object which is itself the result of an expression -- that's a neat trick.

Comment: @zetetic: I use that when I want to bundle a couple of "procedures" together into a single namespace. A lot of people use a module with only singleton methods for that case, but I think modules are for including, not for bundling methods. If you want a singleton object to hold a bunch of loosely related methods, why not use a singleton object?

Answer (score 1):

You can use enumerators, like this:

```
l = letters.to_enum
p = position.to_enum
a_string = ''
loop do
  a_string << l.next[1] << p.next[1]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```
a_string = ""
my_array.each_with_index { |x, index|
  a_string += letters[my_array[index].to_s] + " " + (position.include?((index+1).to_s) ? position[(index+1).to_s] : "nil")
}
```